# Problem with operator on if statement. (C++)

Tags: c++

Lets say i have a code like this:

So i want to set the `variable1` to `3` and it will do `if(variable>2)`, but when i decrease the `variable1` to `1` in `a==2` it will just go to `a==1` and do the `if(variable1<2)`. How do i fix this?

```
if(a==2)
{
   if(variable1>2)
   {
       cout<<"A";
   }
}
if(a==1)
{
   if(variable1<2)
   {
       cout<<"B";
   }
}
```

What i tried : changed the `<` and `>` to `<<` and `>>`, but it still doesn't work properly...

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do, or where you "decrease" anything. It's even less clear why you thought replacing "less than" with "bitwise shift left" would work better. (`1 << 2` is 4.)

Comment: Please post a [mre]. I presume you have an outer loop wrapping these statements.

Comment: Of course won't the code enter into your if(variable1>2), because you change it's value before that to 1. It is unclear what you want to do. Not related: I assume variable1 is defined before this code snipplet's scope.

Comment: @nebulator0 i want the code to run if(variable1>2) but when i decrease the value of variable1 to 1 it will just go to if(variable1<2) in if(a==1) (Note : My a variable value is 2 not 1 so it will not go to if(a==1)

Comment: use `else if (a == 1)` or look up the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are trying to articulate.  I might be wrong though.

```cpp
if (a == 2 || variable1 > 2){
    cout << "A";
}
if (a == 1 && variable1 < 2){
    cout << "B";
}
```